# Accepts Nested Attributes For through a STI table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables - `stage` and `list`. There are two models that inherit from each table - `PipelistStage/HotlistStage` and `Pipelist/Hotlist`. A pipelist/hotlist has_many pipelist_stages/hotlist_stages, and should accept nested attributes for the respective association.

Here's a brief implementation of these models:

Stages:

```
class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.types
    %w(PipelistStage HotlistStage)
  end
end

class PipelistStage < Stage
  # Implementation similar to HotlistStage
end

class HotlistStage < Stage
  belongs_to :hotlist, inverse_of: :hotlist_stages
end
```

and Lists...

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.types
    %w(Hotlist Pipelist)
  end
end

class Hotlist < List
  has_many :hotlist_stages, inverse_of: :hotlist

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hotlist_stages, allow_destroy: true
end

class Pipelist < List
  # Implementation similar to Hotlist
end
```

The issue I'm running into is when I try to update HotlistStagesAttributes through a Hotlist. I get the error 'no such column: stages.hotlist_id`. the accepts_nested_...

Is there any way to make accepts_nested_attributes_for refer to the `stages.list_id` column, rather than `stages.hotlist_id`?

If there's anything I can explain more clearly, please let me know.
Thank you!!

Comment: You don't need `self.types` in your superclasses.